# Add text/content to PDF files (Angular)

Tags: node.js, angular

I work on project and try to implement signature pad on pdf file.
I make a signature with angular2-signaturepad package and view the pdf file with ng2-pdf-viewer.
now i'm looking for a way
to add the signature to Existing pdf file.
What is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps using Html2canvas in anglar. you could send your html content to pdf and view it.
Example function

```
htmlToPdf() {
var data = document.getElementById('html2pdf'); // You can pass the id here for your signature
html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {      
  var imgWidth = 208;
  var pageHeight = 100;
  var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
  var heightLeft = imgHeight;
  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
  let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
  var position = 0;
  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 3, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  pdf.fromHTML()
  pdf.save(this.data+'.pdf'); // Generated PDF
});
```

}